# How to OFF the indexer programmatically in Eclipse (Oxygen version)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I need to OFF the indexer programmatically in C/C++ perspective while loading the Eclipse (i.e. OFF the indexer programmatically every-time when the Eclipse is loading). How can I disable the indexer programmatically? Is there is any possibility to pass an argument to OFF indexer before loading of the Eclipse?

Comment: Could you explain why you need to do it programatically? Why is it not good enough to disable the indexer in the settings?

Comment: Yes because, I am developing a eclipse based new tool.To make more user friendly to the user, I am using the following use case, the indexer should not start once the eclipse gets loaded(by default it should be in OFF mode). When the user requires the indexer, he will ON by using the button in the menu bar(i.e programatically calling the indexer in background). Is there is any possibility to off  the indexer at every time when the eclipse gets loading? Could you please suggest the best idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the indexer programmatically using something like `IPDOMManager.setDefaultIndexerId(IPDOMManager.ID_NO_INDEXER)`.

You can also use `IPDOMManager.setIndexerId()` to do it per project.

`IPDOMManager` is a public CDT API in the package `org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom`.